# How to count databases elements in a range of date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, group-by

In an SQL Server procedure, I need to get all rows matching some constraints(simple where conditions), and then group them by month.

The goal is to create a graph(in Sql server reporting services), which display all data.

I've already something like this:

```
Select Count(*) AS Count, Month(a.issueDate) AS Month, Year(a.issueDate) AS Year
FROM MyTable a
WHERE
....
GROUP BY YEAR(a.issueDate), MONTH(a.issueDate)
```

I got my data, I got my graph, but the problem is that if I've NOT any rows in "`MyTable`", which match my `Where` conditions, I won't have any rows.

The result is that I've a graph Starting with january, skipping february, and then displaying march.

I cannot post-process data since it's directly connected to the SQL Server Reporting Services report.

Since I have this problem for  ~20 stored procedure, I will appreciate to have the simpliest way of doing it.

Thank you very much for your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want a specific year:

```
DECLARE @year INT;
SET @year = 2012;

DECLARE @start SMALLDATETIME;
SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0);

;WITH y AS (SELECT TOP (12) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1
  FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id])
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @start), COUNT(t.issueDate)
  FROM y
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MyTable AS t
  ON t.issueDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @start)
  AND t.issueDate < DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn + 1, @start)
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @start);
```

If it's not a specific year, then you can do it slightly differently to cover any date range, as long as you provide the 1st day of the 1st month and the 1st day of the last month (or pass 4 integers and construct the dates manually):

```
DECLARE @startdate SMALLDATETIME, @enddate SMALLDATETIME;
SELECT @startdate = '20111201', @enddate = '20120201';

;WITH y AS (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @startdate, @enddate)+1)
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @startdate), COUNT(t.issueDate)
  FROM y
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MyTable AS t
  ON t.issueDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @startdate)
  AND t.issueDate < DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn + 1, @startdate)
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, y.rn, @startdate);
```

Comment: That shortcuts mine quite nicely :)

Comment: Seems to be great, but is there a way to iterate no only in the same year? I don't know very well this "With" synthax, and I cannot find how to handle the "december to february"

Comment: I tried your example, but, if I've nothing which match the "ON" constraint(no element in this range), I still get 1 in the count(*), since it's a LEFT join.

Comment: And the problem is that if I filter with a "NOT NULL", I got the initial problem, without any rows returned for empty rows

Comment: I think I found something: If I do a COUNT() on a column that is on a joined table, I get 0 if values are NULL

Comment: Yes, like I said, it works with the count() on some field on the "Right" side. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In report builder, right click on the date axis, select properties, and then set the axis up as a date range, it will add the empty columns for you, and you won't have to change your SQL

Comment: I will try tomorrow :) If it works it will be the better solution. I just don't know if I can then display only the month+year and not the day.

Comment: So I tried your proposition, I effectively got several new label in the X axis, but I get no data point on the Y axis(not even a 0), so since it's a curve graph, I only got curve between really existing points.

Comment: As you're not showing continuous data, are you sure that a curve is the most appropriate chart type?

Comment: I'm showing continuous data, the number of element for each month, but if I've 0 element in a month, it doesn't mean that it's not  continous.

Comment: I believe that individual months are discrete, not continuous (you cannot have January and a half).

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a table (a Table variable would work best here) that contains all year/month combinations from your minimum to maximum.

You then need to cross join this with your main query to get results for all year/months ready for the graph.